# Provide way to specify field order in $project on using mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, sql-order-by, field, preserve

I am trying to extract documents from Mongo DB based on field 'Type' with specific order in the results. Results are retrieved correctly, but the results are not preserving the fields order which is given in the query.

I have included the working code snippets below, Can someone help me how to update equivalent Java code based on my code snippets.

```
Mongo query is as below :- (Which retrieves data)
==========================================
    db.getCollection('elements').aggregate([
        {$match : {'Type' : {$eq : 'ALM_Project'}}},
        { $project:  {
            _id: 0,
            'ID' : 1,
            'Summary' : 1,
            'Created Date' : 1
          }},
        ])

Equivalent Java code is as below :-
==============================================================
 AggregateIterable<Document> documents = getMongoCollection()
        .aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(andQuery),
            Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(
                   Projections.include("ID", "Summary", "Created Date"),
                   Projections.exclude("_id")))));

Mongo query is as below :- (Added the fields preserving code)
===============================================================
db.getCollection('elements').aggregate([
{$match : {'Type' : {$eq : 'ALM_Project'}}},
{ $project:  {
    _id: 0,
    'ID' : 1,
    'Summary' : 1,
    'Created Date' : 1
  }},

 { "$project": {
        "ID": "$ID",
        "Summary": "$Summary",
        "Created Date": "$Created Date"
    }} 
])
```

Mongo query is working perfectly by preserving the fields order. Can some one let me know how could i update java code based on this.

Comment: What specific Java driver and MongoDB server versions do you use.

Comment: Mongo Java driver is 3.8 and MongoDB server is 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MongoDB [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) to output Java code from your pipeline.  Here is the sample code.

```
Arrays.asList(match(eq("Type", "ALM_Project")), 
  project(fields(excludeId(), 
  include("ID", "Summary", "Created Date"))), 
  project(computed("ID", "$ID"), 
  computed("Summary", "$Summary"), 
  computed("Created Date", "$Created Date")))
```